# Prove that the union of one set is equal to another set.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that:
$$
\bigcup\limits_{w=(0,1)} [w,4-2w] = (0,4)
$$

I know we have to show that

(i) If $x \in \bigcup\limits_{w=(0,1)} [w,4-2w]$ then $x \in (0,4)$

(ii) If $x \in (0,4)$ then $x \in \bigcup\limits_{w=(0,1)} [w,4-2w]$

The results are obviously true since 0 < min $x$ and max $x$ < 4, but how do I formulate the proof with sufficient rigour?

Comment: Surely you mean $$\bigcup\limits_{w\in(0,1)} [w,4-2w] = (0,4)?$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Given intervals forms a descending chain, as the value of w increase in (0,1). So, for finding the union just do find the limit of end points as x tends to 0.

Answer (score 1):

(i) is trivially obvious:  There is a $0\lt w\lt 1$ such that $w\le x \le 4-2w$.  Since $w\gt 0$ and $4-2w\lt 4$, $0\lt x \lt 4$.

(ii) Let $u=\frac{x}{2}$ and $v=1-\frac{x}{4}$ then $w=min(u,v)$.  Near $0$, $x\gt w\gt 0$, while near $4$, $4-2w\ge 2+\frac{x}{2}\gt x$.  Net: $w\lt x\lt 4-2w$.

Answer (score 1):

(i) If $x \in \bigcup\limits_{w\in(0,1)} [w,4-2w],$ then $x\in[w,4-2w]$ for some $w\in(0,1)$, so $x\ge w\gt0$ and $x\le4-2w<4$, so $x\in(0,4)$.

On the other hand,

(ii) if $x \in (0,4)$ then (a) $x\in(0,2]$ or (b) $x\in(2,4)$.

If (a) $x\in(0,2]$ then $x\in[w,4-2w]$ with $w=\frac x4\in(0,1)$.

If (b) $x\in(2,4)$ then $x\in[w,4-2w]$ with $w=\frac{4-x}2\in(0,1)$.

In either case, x
$ \in \bigcup\limits_{w\in(0,1)} [w,4-2w]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just show that $\bigcup_{w \in (0,1)} [w, 4-2w]=\bigcup_{n>1}[\frac{1}{n}, 4 - \frac{2}{n}]$